# Create typescript interface with properties based on the values of an enum

Tags: typescript

Given an enum like this

```
enum test {
    A = 'value1',
    B = 'value2'
};
```

I would like to only be able to create objects with these properties given by the values of the enum

```
const data = {
    value1: 'foo',
    value2: 'bar'
}
```

I tried to create an interface which enforces this rule

```
interface ITest {
    [K in test]: string
}
```

or

```
[K in typeof test]: string
[K in test[keyof test]: string
```

I have tried some other combination of `keyof` and `typeof` but none of them worked. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Index signature cannot be of type enum only string, number, symbol and template literal is allowed